# ORACLE SQL STATEMENT IGNORED falta parentesis derecho

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

No encuentro que le falte ningún paréntesis en la linea de set proyecto.activity.full_in =  TO_NUMBER   , lo he revisado unas 20 veces y los paréntesis cierran bien, me presenta 2 errores:  ORA 00907 falta paréntesis derecho y en la linea anterior a esa dice SQL statement ignored.

CODIGO:

Nota: Es un procedimiento de registrar actividad, antes de esto hay mas  pero no quería saturar de código

```
select proyecto.activity.available_space into espacio_disp from proyecto.activity ;
if (espacio_disp = 1 )then  --si solo le queda un espacio lo agrego y pongo los dias en que lo llene

update proyecto.activity
set proyecto.activity.available_space =  proyecto.activity.available_space - 1
where proyecto.activity.id_activity = pid_activity ;

update proyecto.activity 
set proyecto.activity.full_in =   TO_NUMBER( '(select to_char(sysdate,'DD') from dual)' )  -  TO_NUMBER( '(select to_char(proyecto.activity.creation_date,'DD') from PROYECTO.ACTIVITY) ' )  
where proyecto.activity.id_activity = pid_activity ;

insert into proyecto.user_x_activity(id_user_x_activity, id_user, id_activity, id_event)
values (vid_user_x_activity, pid_user, pid_activity, pid_event);


else --si le quedan mas de  1 espacio
```

Comment: Le recomiendo usar las palabras clave en mayúscula. en este [ejemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm#BABDAEGB) se puede ver cómo está organizada la consulta. Organice la consulta y creo que también sería mejor si [edit] y coloca toda la consulta SQL.

Comment: Gracias, el detalle estaba en el TO_NUMBER el cual no se por que razón tenia que tener el segundo parámetro que indicaba el largo del numero a convertir

Comment: AleBerto56, usted puede publicar y aceptar su propia respuesta (lea este **[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)** para mas información). De esta manera ayudará a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El detalle estaba en el TO_NUMBER el cual no se por que razón tenia que tener el segundo parámetro que indicaba el largo del numero a convertir